# Почему компилятор выдаёт что такой позиции(i) в элементах не существует?

Tags: python

Пишу игру Бейглз. Проблема появляется в классе getClues(), компилятор выдаёт что такой позиции(i) в элементах не существует. Прошу помочь.

```
import random

num_digits=3
max_guesses=10

def main():
    print('''Бейглз это дедуктивная логическая игра.
    
Я думаю о {}-значном числе без повторяющихся чисел.
Попробуй угадать его. Я дам несколько подсказок:
Когда я говорю:                  Это значит:
    Пико               Правильная цифра на неправильном месте
    Ферми              Правильная цифра на правильном месте
    Бейглз                    Нет правильных цифр
    
Например, если загаданное число было 248 и ты говоришь 843, то подсказки будут "Ферми Пико"'''.format(num_digits))

    while True:
        secretNum=getSecretNum()
        print('Я задумал число.')
        print('У тебя есть {} попыток чтобы отгадать его'.format(max_guesses))

        numGuesses=1
        while numGuesses<=max_guesses:
            guess=''
            while len(guess) != num_digits or not guess.isdecimal():
                print('Попытка №{}: '.format(numGuesses))
                guess=input('> ')

            clues=getClues(guess, secretNum)
            print(clues)
            numGuesses+=1

            if guess==secretNum:
                break
            if numGuesses>max_guesses:
                print('У тебя закончились попытки')
                print('Ответом было {}.'.format(secretNum))

        print('Вы хотите сыграть ещё раз?(да или нет)')
        if not input('> ').lower().startswith('y'):
            break
    print('Спасибо за игру!')

def getSecretNum():
    numbers=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    random.shuffle(numbers)
    secretNum=''
    for i in range(num_digits):
        secretNum+=str(numbers[i])
        return secretNum

def getClues(guess, secretNum):
    if guess==secretNum:
        return 'Ты угадал'

    clues=[]

    for i in range(len(guess)):
        if guess[i]==secretNum[i]:
            clues.append('Ферми')
        elif guess[i] in secretNum:
            clues.append('Пико')
    if len(clues)==0:
        return 'Бейглз'
    else:
        clues.sort()
        return ' '.join(clues)


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: getClues() не класс, а функция. for i in range(len(guess)-1): индексы допустим от 0 до 5 количество илиментов 6

Comment: к сожалению, ничего не поменялось

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал вот так.

```
import random

num_digits = 3
max_guesses = 10


def main():
    print('''Бейглз это дедуктивная логическая игра.

Я думаю о {}-значном числе без повторяющихся чисел.
Попробуй угадать его. Я дам несколько подсказок:
Когда я говорю:                  Это значит:
    Пико               Правильная цифра на неправильном месте
    Ферми              Правильная цифра на правильном месте
    Бейглз                    Нет правильных цифр

Например, если загаданное число было 248 и ты говоришь 843, то подсказки будут "Ферми Пико"'''.format(
        num_digits))

    while True:
        secretNum = getSecretNum()
        print('Я задумал число.')
        print('У тебя есть {} попыток чтобы отгадать его'.format(max_guesses))

        numGuesses = 1
        while numGuesses <= max_guesses:
            guess = ''
            while len(guess) != num_digits or not guess.isdecimal():
                print('Попытка №{}: '.format(numGuesses))
                guess = input('> ')

            clues = getClues(guess, secretNum)
            print(clues)
            numGuesses += 1

            if guess == secretNum:
                break
            if numGuesses > max_guesses:
                print('У тебя закончились попытки')
                print('Ответом было {}.'.format(secretNum))

        print('Вы хотите сыграть ещё раз?(да или нет)')
        if not input('> ').lower().startswith('y'):
            break
    print('Спасибо за игру!')


def getSecretNum():
    numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    secretNum_lst = random.sample(numbers, 3)     <----- поменял
    secretNum = ''.join(map(str, secretNum_lst))  <----- поменял
    return secretNum


def getClues(guess, secretNum):
    if guess == secretNum:
        return 'Ты угадал'

    clues = []
    guess = ''.join(map(str, guess))              <----- поменял
    for i in range(len(guess)):
        if guess[i] == secretNum[i]:
            clues.append('Ферми')
        elif guess[i] in secretNum:
            clues.append('Пико')
    if len(clues) == 0:
        return 'Бейглз'
    else:
        clues.sort()
        return ' '.join(clues)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

В функции def getSecretNum(): на строке return "лишний" знак табуляции. Цикл завершается на первом же прохождении, и в итоге секретное число - из одной цифры. Убери табуляцию на 1 шаг назад, и все будет работать правильно.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).